# How to fix jumping footer?

Tags: html, wordpress, e-commerce, footer

i just finished building eshop, but i have problem with footer, when there is not product in category, footer keep jumping. You can see it there: https://www.anjelska-predajna.sk/product-category/liturgicke-predmety/tymian/

Any idea, how to fix it ? Thank You. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off, the site is amazing, and as i am from Czech republic, I understood it just fine :)
Secondly, your site is made in WordPress. I recommend trying to update your plugins or styling your footer to stay at the bottom like so:

```
footer { bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: Plugins are up to date. Added the snippet for footer to custom css, but it didin't help. Any other tips? Thank You.